# Debian : Apache no muestra imágenes

Tags: php, apache, nginx, debian, apache2

Tengo una máquina configurada con nginx + apache y me resuelve las peticiones correctamente de un proyecto que tengo con PHP7.3, es un proyecto que crea un documento pdf y lo muestra por pantalla.
El problema lo tengo cuando intento mostrar las imagenes con https no me las carga, en cambio si lo hago en http SI.

Si hago http://cars.local/imagenes/logo.png (el navegador lo muestra)
Si hago **https**://cars.local/imagenes/logo.png (el navegador también lo muestra)

El problema lo tengo que **esto si lo muestra por pantalla** dentro de un archivo php

```
<img src="http://cars.local/imagenes/logo.png">
```

En cambio si lo pongo con https, no lo muestra da error

```
<img src="https://cars.local/imagenes/logo.png">
```

La configuración de nginx que tengo es esta

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        root /var/www/html/cars/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name cars.local;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

La configuración de apache es esta otra

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName cars.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cars/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cars-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cars-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué error te dan los logs?